# Perl script to compare file contents of dirA with file contents of dirB and output the difference in a separate file

Tags: perl, file, compare, directory

I am just a beginner at perl and I need help with the following.

DirA and DirB have files f1 ,f2 ,f3 ,f4, f5 (not necessarily 5 in number). I need to compare the contents of f1 in DirA with contents of f1 in DirB and output the result in f1_diff. Similarly need to do this for all files in directories A and B. So in the above case assuming the contents of all files are different, Script will output 5 files f1_diff,f2_diff,f3_diff,f4_diff,f5_diff which has the missing lines of both f1 DirA and f1 DirB.

For example, if

```
f1 dir A has  line1, line2,     line3, line4xxxx, line5   
f1 dir B has  line1, line2xxxx, line3, line4,     line5
```

f1_diff should have

```
line2 --> line2xxxx

line4xxxx -->line4
```

Can someone please help me with this.

**Update:**
I have the below script right now and need to add the following.
Filename:   # of different lines
File 1 – 1 
File 2  - 30
File 3 – missing in dir1
File 3a – missing in dir2

Secondly the number of lines differing. Can someone help me modify the same

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Main; { 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
my $DirA;
my $DirB;
my $y;

print ("\nChoose one of the entries below\n");
print ("e1\e2\e3\n\n");

print("Enter here --->");
my $dir = <>;  
chomp($dir);    

if ($dir eq "e1"){

$DirA = "./dir1";
$DirB = "./dir2";
}

elsif ($dir eq "e2"){
$DirA = "./dir3";
$DirB = "./dir4";
}

else{
$DirA = "./dir5";
$DirB = "./dir6";
}

opendir my($dh), "$DirA" or die "Couldn't open dir DirA!";
my @files = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;
system("rm -rf diffs");
system ("mkdir diffs");

foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if -d $file;
    my $diff = `diff -y --suppress-common-lines "$DirA/$file" "$DirB/$file"`;
    open DIFF_FILE, ">$file"."_diff";
    print DIFF_FILE $diff;
    close DIFF_FILE;#}
}
    chdir("./diffs/");
    my $cwd = cwd();
    system("mv ../*_diff .");
    foreach(glob('*.*')) {
    unlink if (-f $_) && !-s _;
}
 print("Total number of differences = "); system("ls *_diff | wc -l");print("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the use of CPAN Modules to achieve this tasks:

- To find files: [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/lib/File/Find.pm)
- To compare files: [File::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/lib/File/Compare.pm)
- To show file differences: [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Text-Diff-1.41/lib/Text/Diff.pm)

Check if the output format of Text::Diff is what you need, it offers configuration features

Comment: Text::Diff::OldStyle and Text::Diff:Table look apt. That format is something what I am looking for. But I needed some help with the code

Comment: @Rancho : You need to try code something yourself first... feel free to get back with new questions if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Text::Diff`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::Diff;
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my($dh), "DirA" or die "Couldn't open dir DirA!";
my @files = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if -d $file;
    my $diff = diff "DirA/$file", "DirB/$file";
    open DIFF_FILE, ">$file"."_diff";
    print DIFF_FILE $diff;
    close DIFF_FILE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually when I use "use Text::Diff" or even "use File::Compare" or similar commands I get an error message Can't locate Text/Diff.pm @INC compilation aborted. I am trying to run this script on unix. Should something be added?

Comment: You haven't yet installed this package. If you use ActivePerl on Windows, type `ppm install Text::Diff` in cmd prompt; if you're using *nix, use `cpanm Text::Diff`.

Comment: Thanks a lot will install that

Comment: Is there a way to write the same without using the use Text::Diff or other similar commands? This is for some company and it doesn't allow me to install anything in the servers?

Comment: If you're using *nix, just replace `my $diff = diff "DirA/$file", "DirB/$file";` with `my $diff = \`diff "DirA/$file" "DirB/$file";\``.

Comment: Ok will try that..I can remove the use Text::Diff right? That is where my error is since I am not allowed to install

Comment: Yes feel free to remove that line

Comment: Thanks it works! :) How do I modify the same to "Only if a file exists" create a new diff file.. I tried something like while $diff!=0 and unless -e $diff..But everything gives me a syntax error

Comment: I tried to put one more foreach stmt inside..But doesn't seem like it is outputting any diff file with this change                     foreach $diff(@_){
    open DIFF_FILE, ">$file"."_diff";
    print DIFF_FILE $diff;
    close DIFF_FILE;}
}

Comment: NEver mind I found it.. This one works..                  foreach(glob('*.*')) {
unlink if (-f $_) && !-s _;
}

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if *parallel* is available :

```
ls dirA/f* | parallel 'echo {} - dirB/{/} >>{/}_dif ; diff {} dirB/{/} >> {/}_dif '
```

Comment: Thanks Sidharth. I guess I don't have that parallel switch. I will look it up online and figure out how to install

Comment: parallel can be downloaded from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and its man page is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)